# NancyFx: static file not found when file name has a plus sign

Tags: macos, mono, nancy

I'm running NancyFx on Mono/ASP.NET (Mac OS X) and currently I am not able to retrieve a file that contains a plus sign in its filename. All other files without a symbol work fine and I've confirmed it is not a permission issue.

`+1.png` is the file's name. I've tried making a request to get `%2B1.png` instead and it did not work.

I'm probably missing something obvious. Help? :)

Comment: That's tricky because + is treated as a space. Can you just avoid using silly characters in file names?

Comment: That's what I thought. Well, I'm using this emoji parser that provides a set of image files that contain silly characters so changing it could be a lot of work.